# Models /textures/music corrupted!

Tags: c++, glut

I'm making a 3d rpg game. Everything seems to work on other computer. But when I open my game in my computer, the polygons gets crazy everywhere filled with random polygons. Textures will get rainbow effects and distorted music plays backs.
Everything is corrupted, even the collision detection.

I think I have memory corruption but other games are ok...
I'm using the FreeGlut library.
Very basic obj loader and the Windows OS original playsound library.
Compiler: Visual Studio 2017...

Comment: Are both computers running the same OS? Can you describe the steps you took to run the game on another computer? Did you compile it again on the other computer or did you just send the executables? Does the other computer have the proper libraries installed to run the game? (OpenGL, FreeGlut etc)

Comment: Same operating system. I sended directly executables. Proper libraries installed.

Comment: Did you try running the game from the command line and seeing if there is any error showing up?

Comment: I figured out the problem i used special characters on variables and file names.Like iÜşĞ

Comment: If that solved your problem, make an answer explaining how you solved it and mark it as "accepted". This way your question will show up as having been answered already.

Comment: If it's your game, and you developed it on your computer, how come it did not work in the first place when you were developing it?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed by changing special characters : üĞI to uGi

Comment: Where were the characters you changed? As written, this answer doesn't provide enough info to someone who might have the same problem.